# I need to type number 2 times after my scanner scan the input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Could you help me to understand why I need to type 2 times to allow scanner to scan my input data.
What I am basically check in below piece of code is to validate if number is a int type and is above 0 to ask number of players playing the game (guessing number game)

Validation code works perfectly fine but...I need to type digit 2 times...

```
package pakiet;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GraModyfikacjaLiczbyGraczy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int los = rand.nextInt(11);
        int liczbaGraczy;  // number of players

        Scanner scan7 = new Scanner(System.in); // zamknac
        System.out.println("Type number of players");

        while (!scan7.hasNextInt() || scan7.nextInt() < 0) {
            System.out.println("Type number of players");
            scan7 = new Scanner(System.in);

        }
        liczbaGraczy = scan7.nextInt();
```

Comment: Your asking twice for a number: first in the while-condition and second after the while-loop. Maybe it would be better to put the value in a variable and use that instead of the second nextInt()-call.

Comment: @Tomek I have updated the code for you case and it taking input only one time you can check.

Comment: @Ralf Renz can you help me and explain how the code will look like with your recommendation? I don't quite get it....

Comment: @Tomek: I think the answer of Dipankar below shows how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialize  `Scanner` 2 times thats why -

In while loop -

```
while (!scan7.hasNextInt() || scan7.nextInt() < 0) {
    System.out.println("Type number of players");
    //Issue here
    scan7 = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

You can simply use `scan7.next()` for next input.

You can use `do-While` loop properly to achieve this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int los = rand.nextInt(11);
        int liczbaGraczy;  // number of players

        Scanner scan7 = new Scanner(System.in); // zamknac
        System.out.println("Type number of players");

        do {
            while (!scan7.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println(" Type number of players :");
                scan7.next();
            }
            liczbaGraczy = scan7.nextInt();
        }while (liczbaGraczy < 0);


        System.out.println("Number of players :"+liczbaGraczy);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: while (!scan7.hasNextInt() || scan7.nextInt() < 0) {
    System.out.println("Type number of players");
    scan7.next()
    scan7 = new Scanner(System.in);
} In this way I need to type numer 3 times......

Comment: @TomekMłynarski I have updated the code have a look.

Comment: Works as expected, thank you for your time, appreciated !